# Deleting tree structure in C++

Tags: c++, c++98

I'm supposed to write implementation of tree in C++, and I struggle with writing destructor for Node in this tree. I'm not sure if it clears the whole structure in a proper way. Can you help me with that? (I have to use C++98, maybe it will explain storing raw pointers in the vector).

Header file:

```
class dynamicNode {

public:
    dynamicNode();
    ~dynamicNode();
    void setValue(int newValue);
    int getChildrenNumber();
    void addChild();
    dynamicNode* getChild(int index);
    void printValue();
    void printAllBelow();
private:
    dynamicNode* parent;
    std::vector<dynamicNode*> children;
    int value;



};
```

Implementation(I have only included methods that are related to structure of the tree):

```
dynamicNode::dynamicNode() {
    value = 0;
    parent = NULL;
}

dynamicNode::~dynamicNode() {
    if (!children.empty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {
            delete children.at(i);
        }
        children.clear();
    }

}

void dynamicNode::addChild() {
    dynamicNode* newChild = new dynamicNode();
    newChild->parent = this;
    children.push_back(newChild);
}
```

Comment: The destructor code looks fine to me.  (You could get rid of the `if (!children.empty())` test  and the `children.clear()` line, if you want, since they aren't necessary, but they don't hurt anything, either)

Comment: Looks OK to me, apart from the fact the object cannot be copied. So either you need to define a copy constructor and an assignment operator. Or (more likely) just delete them so you don't end up copying accidentally. Just add `dynamicNode(const dynamicNode&) = delete;` and `dynamicNode& operator=(const dynamicNode&) = delete;` to your class for this.

Comment: From what we see there is no issue. However, we do not know what you're doing in other functions and whether or not you leave some nodes unreferenced and lost in the heap causing memory leaks. The problem isn't always the destructors when it comes to memory leaks.

Comment: @john `dynamicNode(const dynamicNode&) = delete;` is not allowed in C++98

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) What is your actual question?

Comment: @ThomasSablik Good point. In that case declare them as private.

Comment: @MartinYork It's part of the question _"I have to use C++98"_ Probably because the teacher or professor doesn't know modern C++

Comment: Looks Like the code should work as expected. You can post it on https://codereview.stackexchange.com to get a detailed review.

Comment: @ThomasSablik: Oops. Missed that.

Answer (score 1):

The destructor can be simplified and it should use the correct type for the index:

```
dynamicNode::~dynamicNode() {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < children.size(); ++i)
        delete children[i];
}
```

`dynamicNode::addChild` leaks memory if `std::vector::push_back` throws `std::length_error` or `std::bad_alloc`. That could be a problem if the application can recover from these exceptions. A fix to avoid leaking memory is:

```
void dynamicNode::addChild() {
    std::auto_ptr<dynamicNode> newChild(new dynamicNode()); // Delete if children.push_back throws.
    newChild->parent = this;
    children.push_back(newChild.get());
    newChild.release();
}
```